# Tableau error notation in brackets meaning

Tags: google-bigquery, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

In Tableau I received the following error message:

The Google BigQuery service was unable to compile the query.
Name Field1 is ambiguous inside Custom SQL Query at [62:33]

My BQ Query seems to work fine in BQ, but when copy paste in Tableau the above error shows.
In order for me to track the error, I want to understand the error message.

What does **[62:33]** refer to? My query is only 47 lines of code, so I can't really seem to grasp the meaning of this notation...

Comment: can you provide the query

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.